# PRAW : How to breakthrough the number limit of using praw to get the comments of reddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbKH.png)

When I use this praw library to crawl content on the reddit community, the number never exceeds 1,000. I also considered the pushshift library to solve this problem, but this library is no longer maintained and cannot be used. So, are there any other ideas to solve this problem?

```
reddit_authorized = praw.Reddit(client_id=client_id,
                                    client_secret=client_secret,
                                    user_agent=user_agent)

    name_subreddit = "python"
    number = 0
    subreddit = reddit_authorized.subreddit(name_subreddit)
    for submission in subreddit.controversial(limit = 990):
        print(f"submission.title = {submission.title}")
        print(f"submission.score = {submission.score}")
        print(f"submission.id = {submission.id}")
        print(f"submission.url = {submission.url}")
        print("\n"+"="*100+"\n")
        number = number +1
    print(F"number = {number}")
```

I have tried searching for corresponding solutions on stackoverflow and Google. The answer is to use the pushshift library to solve the problem, or use the timestamp interface of the crawl library to crawl forward 1,000 pieces of data after reaching the specified time. Method 1 already stated in the problem description that the library is no longer available. Method 2 [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940262/getting-more-than-1000-search-results-upper-bound-with-praw) and found that the problem could not be solved.